# TableView + CoreData : Add and Refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

Everyone I'm using coredata in my iOS application : my problem is that it just add the element that i need once and then it refuse to add any other element. 
and show me always this error :

> **reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]**

How can i make the table view update it self and always show me the last results.
Can any one check with me this code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:       (NSInteger)section
{

    //return 3;
    return _affichdata1.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell* mycell=[tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellH" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Planificateur1 *p1=[_affichdata1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mycell.textLabel.text = p1.heuredep[indexPath.row];

    return mycell;
}
```

Comment: If you're having trouble adding new objects to Core Data, you should include the code where you are attempting to add new objects to Core Data.

Comment: no for the first time it work and object is added to core data and showed in my table view  but when i try again i get that error @Tom Harrington

Comment: This code does not cause the error.

Comment: How you are adding new object, add code?

Comment: @RohitKP 
i'm parsing in a view controller and when i click a button i saved array in a table view in an other viewcontroller  but it just work once in the beginning in the tryial i get the error that just put it .

Comment: Put code which creates problem, you are saying that you saved array in table view that means what?

Comment: You're not getting answers because you are not providing enough detail for an answer. Somewhere, someplace, you are modifying `_affichdata1`, and the problem **probably** occurs where you're trying to use it. But without knowing how you're modifying it, nobody can possibly tell you what's wrong.